# Prove the probability $(4<X<8)\ge 0.91$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be random varible such that $\mathbb{E}X=6$ and $\mathbb{D}X=0.36$. Prove that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(4<X<8\right)\ge 0.91.$$

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality. Try subtracting $\mu$ from the inequality and rewriting it in the right form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1 - P(4 < X < 8) = 1 - P( |X - 6| < 2) = 1 - P(|X-EX| \ge 2) \le \frac{DX}{2^2} = \frac{0.36}{4}$ according Chebyshev's inequality. Hence $ P(4 < X < 8) \ge 0.91$.